# How to convert PFX to PNG base64 for digital signature

Tags: java, itext, pdfbox, digital-signature

I have a code snippet that inserts a digital signature into a PDF. The code is as below:

```
package my.digital.signature;

import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import org.apache.pdfbox.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.form.PDFormXObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationWidget;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAppearanceDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAppearanceStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.PDSignature;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.SignatureOptions;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDField;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDSignatureField;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.Matrix;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/digital")
public class CpDigitalSignController {

    @GetMapping(path = "/sign")
    public void addVisibleSignatureToPdf() throws IOException {
        String pdfInBase64 = "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";
        String signatureImageInBase64 = "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";
        long signatureTime = 1692617329341L;

        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(Base64.getDecoder().decode(pdfInBase64));

        PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();

        signature.setType(COSName.getPDFName("Sig"));
        signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
        signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ETSI_CADES_DETACHED);

        // The signing date, needed for a valid signature
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        final Date signingDate = new Date(signatureTime);
        cal.setTime(signingDate);
        signature.setSignDate(cal);
        SignatureOptions options = new SignatureOptions();

        // Enough room for signature, timestamp and OCSP for baseline-LT profile.
        options.setPreferredSignatureSize(SignatureOptions.DEFAULT_SIGNATURE_SIZE);

        // The code for visible signature starts here
        int pageNum = 0; // Page numbering starts from zero.
        options.setPage(pageNum);
        Rectangle2D humanRect = new Rectangle2D.Float(20, 10, 200, 100);

        PDRectangle rect = createSignatureRectangle(document, humanRect);
        options.setVisualSignature(createVisualSignatureTemplate(document, pageNum, rect, signatureImageInBase64));

        document.addSignature(signature, options);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        document.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(baos);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("prepared.pdf");
        document.save(outputStream);

        outputStream.close();
        document.close();
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(options);
    }

    private PDRectangle createSignatureRectangle(PDDocument doc, Rectangle2D humanRect) {
        float x = (float) humanRect.getX();
        float y = (float) humanRect.getY();
        float width = (float) humanRect.getWidth();
        float height = (float) humanRect.getHeight();
        PDPage page = doc.getPage(0);
        PDRectangle pageRect = page.getCropBox();
        PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle();

        // Signature image should be at the same position regardless of page rotation.
        // Coordinates start from bottom left.
        switch (page.getRotation()) {
        case 90:
            rect.setLowerLeftX(pageRect.getWidth() - y - height);
            rect.setUpperRightX(pageRect.getWidth() - y);
            rect.setLowerLeftY(x);
            rect.setUpperRightY(x + width);
            break;
        case 180:
            rect.setLowerLeftX(pageRect.getWidth() - x - width);
            rect.setUpperRightX(pageRect.getWidth() - x);
            rect.setLowerLeftY(pageRect.getHeight() - y - height);
            rect.setUpperRightY(pageRect.getHeight() - y);
            break;
        case 270:
            rect.setLowerLeftX(y);
            rect.setUpperRightX(y + height);
            rect.setLowerLeftY(pageRect.getHeight() - x - width);
            rect.setUpperRightY(pageRect.getHeight() - x);
            break;
        case 0:
        default:
            rect.setLowerLeftX(x);
            rect.setUpperRightX(x + width);
            rect.setLowerLeftY(y);
            rect.setUpperRightY(y + height);
            break;
        }

        return rect;
    }

    // Create a template PDF document with empty signature and return it as a
    // stream.
    private InputStream createVisualSignatureTemplate(PDDocument srcDoc, int pageNum, PDRectangle rect,
            String imageInBase64) throws IOException {
        try (PDDocument doc = new PDDocument()) {
            PDPage page = new PDPage(srcDoc.getPage(pageNum).getMediaBox());
            doc.addPage(page);
            PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm(doc);
            doc.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);
            PDSignatureField signatureField = new PDSignatureField(acroForm);
            PDAnnotationWidget widget = signatureField.getWidgets().get(0);
            List<PDField> acroFormFields = acroForm.getFields();
            acroForm.setSignaturesExist(true);
            acroForm.setAppendOnly(true);
            acroForm.getCOSObject().setDirect(true);
            acroFormFields.add(signatureField);

            widget.setRectangle(rect);

            // from PDVisualSigBuilder.createHolderForm()
            PDStream stream = new PDStream(doc);
            PDFormXObject form = new PDFormXObject(stream);
            PDResources res = new PDResources();
            form.setResources(res);
            form.setFormType(1);
            PDRectangle bbox = new PDRectangle(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
            Matrix initialScale = null;
            int pageRotation = srcDoc.getPage(0).getRotation();
            switch (pageRotation) {
            case 90:
                form.setMatrix(AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(1));
                initialScale = Matrix.getScaleInstance(bbox.getWidth() / bbox.getHeight(),
                        bbox.getHeight() / bbox.getWidth());
                break;
            case 180:
                form.setMatrix(AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(2));
                break;
            case 270:
                form.setMatrix(AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(3));
                initialScale = Matrix.getScaleInstance(bbox.getWidth() / bbox.getHeight(),
                        bbox.getHeight() / bbox.getWidth());
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            form.setBBox(bbox);

            // From PDVisualSigBuilder.createAppearanceDictionary()
            PDAppearanceDictionary appearance = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
            appearance.getCOSObject().setDirect(true);
            PDAppearanceStream appearanceStream = new PDAppearanceStream(form.getCOSObject());
            appearance.setNormalAppearance(appearanceStream);
            widget.setAppearance(appearance);

            try (PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(doc, appearanceStream)) {
                if (initialScale != null) {
                    cs.transform(initialScale);
                }

                if (imageInBase64 != null) {
                    byte[] image = Base64.getDecoder().decode(imageInBase64);
                    cs.saveGraphicsState();
                    PDImageXObject img = PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray(doc, image, "signature.png");

                    float imageWidth = bbox.getWidth();
                    float imageHeight = bbox.getHeight();
                    if (pageRotation == 90 || pageRotation == 270) {
                        imageWidth = bbox.getHeight();
                        imageHeight = bbox.getWidth();
                    }
                    cs.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
                    cs.restoreGraphicsState();
                }

            }

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            doc.save(baos);
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
        }
    }
}
```

But here `signatureImageInBase64` should be derived from a PFX file that is a digital ID generated using Adobe Acrobat.

I've tried to convert the file to base64 and use it, but it doesn't work stating invalid PNG image. How do I use the PFX file to digitally sign a PDF document using Java code?

Comment: You say *`signatureImageInBase64` should be derived from a pfx file* but how exactly? A pfx file is not some special image format, so there is no canonical transformation. Thus, how do you want to derive the bitmap?

Answer (score 1):

"Switching" a pfx file into an image does not work. PFX is not an image file type but a kind of keystore. The question is who signs the document. Normally you would capture a handwritten signature and create an image out of it. If the PFX file contains the personal certificate of the signee then you can extract the name and other information and create an image by yourself.

Please note that the following code is not complete but provides some general idea how you could do it. You need to "design" your own image. So where to put what information (like name, location, hash ...)? Also the code assumes that it is a personal certificate of a user.

```
    private OutputStream createVisualSignatureImage(String path2Keystore, String password, Rectangle2D humanRect) throws IOException {

    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    keystore.load(new FileInputStream(path2Keystore), password.toCharArray());

    String alias = keystore.aliases().nextElement();
    Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);

    // Extracting information from the certificate
    X509Certificate x509Cert = (X509Certificate) cert;
    Principal principal = x509Cert.getSubjectDN();
    String subjectDn = principal.getName();
    // You can parse subjectDn to extract specific details like CN, O, etc.

    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage((int)humanRect.getWidth(), (int)humanRect.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();

    // Set font, color etc.
    g2d.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    // Draw text extracted from certificate
    g2d.drawString("Name: " + subjectDn, x, y); // Position and extracted text
    // You can add more details similarly

    g2d.dispose();

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(img, "png", baos);
    
    return baos;
    
}
```

A PDF viewer for instance creates this images like this:

[image]